# How to use find all condition in the layout file main.php in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Iam new to yii 2.0 i want to display all the project names in the layout file.

i can use the following code in layouts->main.php

```
                <?php $model = Project_manage::find()->all(); ?>
```

When i use this code in the main .php

The following Error will come

```
Error (#1)

An internal server error occurred.(These Error are came)
```

in my Bootstrap file the following code is placed

```
Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
Yii::setAlias('console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');

Event::on(View::className(), View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER, function() {
$model = Project_manage::find()->all();
Yii::$app->view->params['model'] = $model;
});
```

The following error will displayed when the above code is placed

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Event' not found in   D:\wamp\www\yii2\common\config\bootstrap.php on line 7
```

In yii 2.0 how to use find all condition in layout file

Kindly help me to fix this,

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked in the log files what the cause of the internal server error is? This might be a 1000 different things. Have you tried commenting the line out and seeing if it works then? Please add some more information. The `ActiveQuery`-functionality you are referring to should just work in the layout file like anywhere else.

Comment: After commenting the $model line it work's fine.But enable the code it show's an error

Comment: Again: Check your logs! I don't see any namespace here, so either you have a `use`-statement at the top of the file, or it simply can't find the `Project_manage`-class at all. Or anything else which we won't know without exact error information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER: Put this in your common\config\bootstrap.php

```
    use yii\base\Event;
    use yii\base\View;

    Event::on(View::className(), View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER, function() {

        $model = Project_manage::find()->all();
        Yii::$app->view->params['model'] = $model;

    });
```

Then in your main layout you can use your model as:

```
$model= $this->params['model'];
```

Comment: When i used the above code i get the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in D:\wamp\www\yii2\frontend\config\bootstrap.php on line 2

MY code in the common\config\bootstrap.php

<?php
class function Event()
{
 Event::on(View::className(), View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER, function() {
 $model = Project_manage::find()->all();
 Yii::$app->view->params['model'] = $model;
 });
}
?>

Comment: Can you please update your question and show what have you put in bootstrap file. In my answer I havent wrote a function that I see in your comment.

Comment: sir, now i update my code kindly check my code please once again

Comment: You havent included the namespace. I have updated the answer, see the first two line and include it on the top in bootstrap file and then check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79385/discussion-between-gautham-m-and-chinmay).